# Looking over a csv file for various conditions

Tags: python

```
00,0,6098
00,1,6098
00,2,6098
00,3,6098
00,4,6094
00,5,6094
01,0,8749
01,1,8749
01,2,8749
01,3,88609
01,4,88609
01,5,88609
01,6,88611
01,7,88611
01,8,88611
02,0,9006
02,1,9006
02,2,4355
02,3,9013
02,4,9013
02,5,9013
02,6,4341
02,7,4341
02,8,4341
02,9,4341
03,0,6285
03,1,6285
03,2,6285
03,3,6285
03,4,6278
03,5,6278
03,6,6278
03,7,6278
03,8,8960
```

I have a csv file and a bit of it is shown above.
What I want to do is if the column 0 has the same value, it makes a an array of column 2, prints the array. ie- for 00, it makes an array-

```
a = [6098,6098,6098,6098,6094,6094]
```

for 01, it makes an array-

a = [8749,8749,88609,88609,88609,88611,88611,88611]
I don't know how to loop over this file.

Comment: Look at `itertools.groupby()`

Comment: If you can't figure it out, please provide your code, what you have tried so far and what are potential error messages, so we can specifically help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution assumes that the first column will appear in sorted order in the file.

```
def main():
    import csv
    from itertools import groupby

    with open("csv.csv") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        rows = [[row[0]] + [int(item) for item in row[1:]] for row in reader]

    groups = {}

    for key, group in groupby(rows, lambda row: row[0]):
        groups[key] = [row[2] for row in group]

    print(groups["00"])
    print(groups["01"])
    print(groups["02"])
    print(groups["03"])

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
[6098, 6098, 6098, 6098, 6094, 6094]
[8749, 8749, 8749, 88609, 88609, 88609, 88611, 88611, 88611]
[9006, 9006, 4355, 9013, 9013, 9013, 4341, 4341, 4341, 4341]
[6285, 6285, 6285, 6285, 6278, 6278, 6278, 6278, 8960]
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use a dictionary in which 00, 01 etc will be the keys and value will be a list. So you need to iterate through the csv data and push these data to corresponding keys.

```
import csv

result = {}

with open("you csv file", "r") as csvfile:
     data = csv.reader(csvfile)
     for row in data:
         if result.has_key(row[0]):
            result[row[0]].append(row[2])
         else:
            result[row[0]] = [row[2]]
print (result)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. It will be helpful for future users as well.

Comment: yeah I added an explanation now, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score -1):

Here

```
from collections import defaultdict
txt = '''00,0,6098
00,1,6098
00,2,6098
00,3,6098
00,4,6094
00,5,6094
01,0,8749
01,1,8749
01,2,8749
01,3,88609
01,4,88609
01,5,88609
01,6,88611
01,7,88611
01,8,88611
02,0,9006
02,1,9006
02,2,4355
02,3,9013
02,4,9013
02,5,9013
02,6,4341
02,7,4341
02,8,4341
02,9,4341
03,0,6285
03,1,6285
03,2,6285
03,3,6285
03,4,6278
03,5,6278
03,6,6278
03,7,6278
03,8,8960'''

data_holder = defaultdict(list)
lines = txt.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    fields = line.split(',')
    data_holder[fields[0]].append(fields[2])
for k,v in data_holder.items():
    print('{} -> {}'.format(k,v))
```

output

```
02 -> ['9006', '9006', '4355', '9013', '9013', '9013', '4341', '4341', '4341', '4341']
03 -> ['6285', '6285', '6285', '6285', '6278', '6278', '6278', '6278', '8960']
00 -> ['6098', '6098', '6098', '6098', '6094', '6094']
01 -> ['8749', '8749', '8749', '88609', '88609', '88609', '88611', '88611', '88611']
```

Comment: I tried using the above code with this but it said 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @abbyad012 Did you try to run the code that I have posted and got this error? Or you tried a different code?